# How to plot Daubechies psi and phi wavelet functions in R?

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

The analysis with wavelets seems to be carried out as a discrete transform via matrix multiplication. So it is not surprising, I guess, that when plotting, for example, D4, the R package `wmtsa` returns the plot:

```
require(wmtsa)
filters <- wavDaubechies("d4")
plot(filters)
```

[image]

The question is how to go from this discretized plot to the plot in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet):

[image]

Please note that I'm not interested in generating these curves precisely with `wmtsa`. Any other package will do - I don't have Matlab or Mathematica. But I wonder if the way to go is to start with translating this Mathematica chunk of code in [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.168556) into R, rather than using built-in functions:

```
Wave1etTransform.m
c[k-1 := c[k] = Daubechies[4][[k+l]];
phi[l] = (l+Sqrt[3])/2 // N;
phi[2] = (l-Sqrt[3])/2 // N;
phi[xJ; xc=0 II x>=3] : = 0
phi[x-?NumberQ] := phi[x] =
N[Sqrt[2]] Sum[c[k] phi[2x-k],{k,0,3}];
```

Comment: I hope I'm not too late. I edited my answer, please see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to plot the wavelet and scaling function all you need are the four numbers shown in the first two plots. I'll focus on plotting the scaling function.

Integer shifts of the scaling function, , form an orthonormal basis of the subspace V<sub>0</sub> of the multiresolution analysis. We also have that V<sub>-1</sub> ⊆ V<sub>0</sub> and that (x/2) ∈ V<sub>-1</sub>. Using this gives us the identity

> (x/2) = ∑<sub>k ∈ ℤ</sub> h<sub>k</sub>(x-k)

Now we just need the values of h<sub>k</sub>. For the Daubechies wavelet these are the values show in the discrete plot you gave (and zero for every other value of k). For an exact value of the h<sub>k</sub>, first let  = (1+sqrt(3))/2. Then we have that

- h<sub>0</sub> = /4
- h<sub>1</sub> = (1+)/4
- h<sub>2</sub> = (2-)/4
- h<sub>3</sub> = (1-)/4

and h<sub>k</sub> = 0 otherwise.

Using these two things we are able to plot the function using what is known as the cascade algorithm. First notice that (0) = (0/2) = h<sub>0</sub>(0) + h<sub>1</sub>(0-1) + h<sub>2</sub>(0-2) + h<sub>3</sub>(0-3). The only way this equation can hold is if (0) = (-1) = (-2) = (-3) = 0. Extending this will show that for x ≦ 0 we have that (x) = 0. Furthermore, a similar argument can show that (x) = 0 for x ≥ 3.

Thus, we only need to worry about x = 1 and x = 2 to find non-zero values of  for integer values of x. If we put x = 2 into the identity for (x/2) we get that (1) = h<sub>0</sub>(2) + h<sub>1</sub>(1). Putting x = 4 into the identity gives us that (2) = h<sub>2</sub>(2) + h<sub>3</sub>(1).

We can rewrite the above two equations as a matrix multiplied by a vector equals a vector. In fact, it will be in the form v = Av (v is the same vector on both sides). This means that v is an eigenvector of the matrix A with eigenvalue 1. But v = ((1), (2)) and so by finding this eigenvector using the standard methods we will be able to find the values of (1) and (2).

In fact, this gives us that (1) = (1+sqrt(3))/2 and (2) = (1-sqrt(3))/2 (this is where those values in the Mathematica code sample come from). Also note that we need to specifically chose the eigenvector of magnitude 2 for this algorithm to work so you *must* use those values for (1) and (2) even though you could rescale the eigenvector.

Now we can find the values of (1/2), (3/2), and (5/2). For example, (1/2) = h<sub>0</sub>(1) and (3/2) = h<sub>1</sub>(2) + h<sub>2</sub>(1).

With these values, you can then find the values of (1/4), (3/4), and so on. Continuing this process will give you the value of  for all dyadic rationals (rational numbers in the form k/2<sup>j</sup>.

The same process can be used to find the wavelet function. You only need to use the four different values shown in the first plot rather than the four shown in the second plot.

I recently implemented this Python. An R implementation will be fairly similar.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def cascade_algorithm(j: int):
    mu = (1 + np.sqrt(3))/2
    h_k = np.array([mu/4, (1+mu)/4, (2-mu)/4, (1-mu)/4])

    # Array to store all the value of phi.
    phi_vals = np.zeros((2, 3*2**j+1), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(3*2**j+1):
        phi_vals[0][i] = i/(2**j)

    calced_vals = np.zeros((3*2**j+1), dtype=np.bool)

    # Input values for 1 and 2.
    phi_vals[1][1*2**j] = (1+np.sqrt(3))/2
    phi_vals[1][2*2**j] = (1-np.sqrt(3))/2

    # We now know the values for 0, 1, 2, and 3.
    calced_vals[0] = True
    calced_vals[1*2**j] = True
    calced_vals[2*2**j] = True
    calced_vals[3*2**j] = True

    # Now calculate for all the dyadic rationals.  
    for k in range(1, j+1):
        for l in range(1, 3*2**k):
            x = l/(2**k)
            if calced_vals[int(x*2**j)] != True:
                calced_vals[int(x*2**j)] = True
                two_x = 2*x
                which_k = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int)
                which_k = ((two_x - which_k > 0) & (two_x - which_k < 3))
                phi = 0
                for n, _ in enumerate(which_k):
                    if which_k[n] == True:
                        phi += h_k[n]*phi_vals[1][int((two_x-n)*2**j)]
                phi_vals[1][int(x*2**j)] = 2*phi

    return phi_vals

phi_vals = cascade_algorithm(10)

plt.plot(phi_vals[0], phi_vals[1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the graphs, then you can use the package "wavethresh" to plot for example the D4 with the following commands:

```
draw.default(filter.number=4, family="DaubExPhase", enhance=FALSE, main="D4 Mother", scaling.function = F) # mother wavelet
draw.default(filter.number=4, family="DaubExPhase", enhance=FALSE, main="D4 Father", scaling.function = T) # father wavelet
```

Notice that the mother wavelet and the father wavelets will be plotted depending on the variable "scaling.function". If true, then it plots the father wavelet (scaling), else it plots the mother wavelet.

If you want to generate it by yourself, without packages, I'd suggest you follow Daubechies-Lagarias algorithm, in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5376528). It is not hard to implement.